# Why QTextBrowser is messing up my HTML code?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtextbrowser

I am trying to create a PDF Invoices, since my requirement is pretty basic I thought of  using HTML + QTextBrowser. I have written functions which will create HTML code according to my needs. For ex if I want to insert text there is a function for that, for inserting table also I have created a function and so on. I am setting this HTML code to QTextBrowser using setHtml() function and then I am trying to create PDF. The problem is I am not getting what I am expecting, the problem is not with my HTML code as I have used the same code and seen in Chrome Browser everything is fine. But the moment I use it in setHtml function, Qt is modifying the html code and the result is undesirable. Below I am posting my code with expected and result images too.

```
void PDF_API::Save(const QString &filePath)
{ 
    QTextDocument document;
    document.setHtml(HTMLCode); // HTMLCode is a QString obj that holds all my html code

    // Creates a copy in html to check the html code. Comment the code if not needed
    QFile file(QDir::currentPath()+"/report.html");
    if(file.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
    {
        file.write(HTMLCode.toStdString().c_str());
        file.close();
    }

    // Printing begins here
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::Tabloid);
    printer.setOutputFileName(filePath);
    printer.setPageMargins(QMarginsF(0.1, 0.01, 0.1, 0.1));
    document.print(&printer);
}
```

The original HTML code before I set it to QTextBrowser

```
"<html><body><p align=\"center\" style=\"color: #000000; font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 12pt; line-height: 100%;\">  <b>CENTER </b> </p><hr><p style = \"text-align:left; color: #ff0000; font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 14pt; line-height: 100%;\"> <b>Left Text</b> <span style = \"float:right; color: #ffff00; font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 14pt; line-height: 100%;\"> <b>Right Text</b> </span> </p></body></html>"
```

The Modified HTML code generated by QTextBrowser

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\np, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n</style></head><body style=\" font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; line-height:100%;\"><span style=\" font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#000000;\">CENTER </span></p>\n<hr />\n<p style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; line-height:100%;\"><span style=\" font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; color:#ff0000;\">Left Text</span><span style=\" font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:14pt; color:#ff0000;\"> </span><span style=\" font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; color:#ffff00;\">Right Text</span><span style=\" font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:14pt; color:#ffff00;\"> </span></p></body></html>"
```

**Note::** The above HTML code is as seen in debugging console which was held in QString

**As seen in Chrome browser using the original html code**
[image]

**As seen in QTextBrowser**
[image]

How can I prevent QTextBrowser from messing up my html code and get my desired result?

**P.S:** This has happened many times before, since before my requirement was only to print the pdf i used external process called wkhtmltopdf process to create pdf, but now in this scenario i want to see the result in application itself.

Comment: `QTextBrowser` supports only a subset of [HTML & CSS](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QTextBrowser` supports only a subset of [HTML & CSS](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html).
For full support try using `QWebView`.

Comment: Yeah I checked that, since i have used only basic html tags like span it should have been supported.I cannot use QWebView since it is not built in my environment, and I don't have time to build QWebView

Comment: Upon further research, turns out that 'float' is partially supported by Qt, that is it is only supported in tables and images.